# http:outbound-gateway with Jackson throws parsing exception for unmatching Response

Tags: java, json, spring-integration

**I have a problem:**

How to handle situation where 3rd party returns json response in the format unknown to http:outbound-gateway (and jackson in it - com.fasterxml.jackson one).

---

Spring Integration Config:

```
<int:chain input-channel="ul_campaignSetup_channel">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="ulHttpOutboundGateway"
                               http-method="POST"
                               url="${request.url}"
                               extract-request-payload="true"
                               error-handler="campaignSetupResponseHandler"
                               expected-response-type="integration.ul.message.CampaignSetupResponse"
                               request-factory="ulRequestFactory">
        <int-http:uri-variable name="url" expression="headers.url"/>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
    <int:service-activator method="handle" ref="campaignSetupResponseHandler" />

    <int:json-to-object-transformer id="myId" />

</int:chain>

<bean id="campaignSetupResponseHandler" class="integration.ul.message.CampaignSetupResponseHandler" />

<bean id="jackson2http" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="ulObjectMapper" />
</bean>

<bean id="ulObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>

<bean id="ulRequestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
    <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
</bean>
```

---

```
public class CampaignSetupResponse {

    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

---

Correct JSON Response from 3rd party (it works):

```
{
  "status" : "1"
}
```

---

Incorrect JSON Response from 3rd party (causes exception):

```
{
  "nonExistingProperty": "non existing value"
}
```

---

**Exception I get:**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "nonExistingProperty" (class integration.ul.message.CampaignSetupResponse), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "status"])
at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@20fddd96; line: 2, column: 27] (through reference chain: integration.ul.message.CampaignSetupResponse["nonExistingProperty"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "nonExistingProperty" (class integration.ul.message.CampaignSetupResponse), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "status"])
at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@20fddd96; line: 2, column: 27] (through reference chain: integration.ul.message.CampaignSetupResponse["nonExistingProperty"])
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:220)
```

---

How can I handle this parsing exception?

I tried few solutions with error channel (http:outbound-gateway doesn't seem to have one) and error-handler (it's more for actual http errors like 500) but couldn't handle that Jackson parsing Exception.

Any ideas more than welcome, cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

What is the interface that has ben agreed upon?
Honestly that second response is not in tune with the interface definition - I'd just get them to fix it. (for me it looks like something on their end, like "status" variable not present or something).
Otherwise you'd need to handle the response yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error handling (`error-channel`) goes on some component upstream of the chain - e.g. whatever is starting your flow.

The error message payload is a `MessagingException` with 2 properties `failedMessage` and `cause`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question which I never replied to, sorry guys about it!

I couldn't get 3rd party to change their response body so eventually I turned off json parsing of the response (json-to-object-transformer)

I parsed it with my own json parser instead, so I could catch the parse exception. Not the cleanest solution, I know, but that was the only thing I could do at the time.